# How to get the socket FD from MySQLdb connection

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I use MySQLdb to fetch data from mysql and I need the connected socket to do someting else。 
Is there some way to get it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples):

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
```

db is what you call your "connected socket"

Comment: what I wanted is the really socket file description~

Comment: why do you need the same socket? Why not open a new one? MySQLdb gives no option to get the raw socket. You could probably inherit from the MySQLdb classes and prevent the socket from closing but I don't see the point.

Comment: Thank you all the same ! I use pymysql instead ~